# How to convert complex JSON to CSV using JQ 1.4

Tags: json, jq

I am using JQ 1.4 on Windows 64 bit machine.

Below are the contents of input file `IP.txt`

```
{
  "results": [
    {
      "name": "Google",
      "employees": [
        {
          "name": "Michael",
          "division": "Engineering"
        },
        {
          "name": "Laura",
          "division": "HR"
        },
        {
          "name": "Elise",
          "division": "Marketing"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "Microsoft",
      "employees": [
        {
          "name": "Brett",
          "division": "Engineering"
        },
        {
          "name": "David",
          "division": "HR"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}

{
  "results": [
    {
      "name": "Amazon",
      "employees": [
        {
          "name": "Watson",
          "division": "Marketing"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

File contains two `"results"`. 1st result containts information for 2 companies: `Google` and `Microsoft`. 2nd result contains information for `Amazon`.
I want to convert this JSON into csv file with company name and employee name.

```
"Google","Michael"
"Google","Laura"
"Google","Elise"
"Microsoft","Brett"
"Microsoft","David"
"Amazon","Watson"
```

I am able to write below script:

```
jq -r "[.results[0].name,.results[0].employees[0].name]|@csv" IP.txt

"Google","Michael"

"Amazon","Watson"
```

Can someone guide me to write the script without hardcoding the index values?

Script should be able generate output for any number `results` and each cotaining information of any number of companies.

I tried using below script which didn't generate expected output:

```
jq -r "[.results[].name,.results[].employees[].name]|@csv" IP.txt
"Google","Microsoft","Michael","Laura","Elise","Brett","David"
"Amazon","Watson"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to flatten down the results first to rows of company and employee names.  Then with that, you can convert to csv rows.

```
map(.results | map({ cn: .name, en: .employees[].name } | [ .cn, .en ])) | add[] | @csv
```

Since you have a stream of inputs, you'll have to slurp (`-s`) it in.  Since you want to output csv, you'll want to use raw output (`-r`).

Comment: Thank you Jeff. This worked perfectly. Can you please tell me where I can learn JQ to understand how this script works? I went through JQ manual. It helps for individual filters. I want to learn how to mix them to create magical solutions link the one you provided.

Comment: The best advice I can give to you is to be aware of all the filters available and understand what they can be used for and use them. Be aware of what filters yield as types, whether it is single values (numbers, objects, arrays, etc.) or multiple values (using []) and how they affect the final result. A strong background in functional programming or other declarative programming styles is a big plus. Just play with it and it'll grow on you.  I just discovered this maybe a few months ago, but within that time, I feel I've learned enough to do just about anything.