# Convert complex JSON (with arrays and different data types) to CSV using JQ?

Tags: json, export-to-csv, jq

I have the following JSON data:

```
   {
        "status": "ok",
        "ok": true,
        "data": "MFR-L",
        "stores": [{
            "name": "KOLL",
            "lat": 52.93128,
            "lng": 6.962956,
            "dist": 1,
            "x10": 1.129,
            "isOpen": true
        },
        {
            "name": "Takst",
            "lat": 52.9523773,
            "lng": 6.981644,
            "dist": 1.3,
            "x10": 1.809,
            "isOpen": false
        }]
    }
```

I'm trying to convert it to a flat file using JQ, but I keep running into all sorts of problems, especially because of the file types ("cannot index boolean with string", etc).

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29764836/how-to-convert-complex-json-to-csv-using-jq-1-4) has helped me flatten the contents of the array so far, like this:

```
jq -r -s 'map(.stores | map({nm: .name, lt: .lat} | [.nm, .lt])) | add [] | @csv
```

How can I get the contents higher up in the hierarchy to map to the array contents?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could always collect the values you want from the parent objects separately from the child objects and combine them later.

e.g.,

```
$ jq -r '[.data] + (.stores[] | [.name, .lat, .lng, .dist]) | @csv' input.json
```

yields

```
"MFR-L","KOLL",52.93128,6.962956,1
"MFR-L","Takst",52.9523773,6.981644,1.3
```

Comment: Hi Jeff. This throws "Cannot iterate over null (null)" . 

I have to point out that I am using jq 1.4 .

Comment: Hello. Nevermind, you are absolutely right, I had a small mistake. This works, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways in which the illustrative JSON might be "flattened" (e.g. to CSV), but the following two approaches may be of interest. (I've omitted the invocation of @csv for ease-of-reading.)

`$ jq '[.data, .stores[][]]' in.json
[
  "MFR-L",
  "KOLL",
  52.93128,
  6.962956,
  1,
  1.129,
  true,
  "Takst",
  52.9523773,
  6.981644,
  1.3,
  1.809,
  false
]`

`$ jq '.data as $data | .stores[] | [$data, .[]]' in.json
[
  "MFR-L",
  "KOLL",
  52.93128,
  6.962956,
  1,
  1.129,
  true
]
[
  "MFR-L",
  "Takst",
  52.9523773,
  6.981644,
  1.3,
  1.809,
  false
]`

Answer (score 0):

Here is another approach which uses jq variables and string interpolation:

```
   .data as $data
 | .stores[]
 | "\($data),\(.name),\(.lat),\(.lng),\(.dist),\(.x10),\(.isOpen)"
```

output with sample data:

```
"MFR-L,KOLL,52.93128,6.962956,1,1.129,true"
"MFR-L,Takst,52.9523773,6.981644,1.3,1.809,false"
```